# template creation in pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have been researching where the ${user_name} and ${user_email} variables are set from the default modules and/or how to create custom variables for module creation. I have read through all of the getting started with pydev. I have tried setting variables in git for a project. Setting environment variables in Python interpreter, setting substitution variables. Stack overflow, eclipse Wiki and several other sources have not provided an answer. I have tried setting the eclipse.ini variables as well.

I am working in Python3, Eclipse Photon, and PyDev 7x.

The question is how can I set a variable in my templates for User (Name), (Email) and Organization as well as license information and so on.

I can create templates and use the system variables without an issue.

There was a question about the module CLI Argparse and user_name in stack overflow but no good answer there either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own template variables you need to use Jython scripting for that.

The are instructions at:

https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pytemplate_defaults.py

Mostly, create your own `pytemplate_xxx.py` and add it to the `Location of additional jython scripts` (see http://www.pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html) adding the template variables you want (use the `pytemplate_defaults.py` as a reference).